# Wrong war file name in deployment directory

Tags: eclipse, maven, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I am having a "404 Not found" error message when visiting at:
http://localhost:8080/bword in Eclipse.

This application is served in Wildfly. In POM.xml, it defines:

```
<artifactId>bword</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>bword</name>
```

However, strange enough, when I run the application in Eclipse with Wildfly 9.0 configured as the server, what's deployed into wildfly/standone/deployments/ is bbword.war, as below:

```
[abigail@localhost wildfly-9.0.2.Final]$ ls standalone/deployments/
bbword.war/          bbword.war.deployed
```

Which is wrong, it should be "bword.war/" and "bword.war.deployed".

Outside of Eclipse, if I "mvn clean package" under the project "bword", I can get the "bword.war" under the target/ directory.

Please see the attachment screenshot for reference. I suspect somewhere in my pom, or eclipse, or whatever place, there is a misconfiguration of "bbword", instead of "bword", but I can't really find it. I can't find any trace of "bbword". What dictates the name of the deployed war file under deployments?

See attached.

[image]

Edited (Part of the POM.xml):

```
<build>
            <!-- Set the name of the war, used as the context root when the app 
                is deployed -->
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- WildFly plugin to deploy war -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Compiler plugin enforces Java 1.6 compatibility and activates 
                    annotation processors -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

One more addition:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
17:32:35,508 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
17:32:35,702 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
17:32:35,761 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) starting
17:32:36,573 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
17:32:36,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found bbword.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called bbword.war.dodeploy
17:32:36,625 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
17:32:36,647 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
```

......

This is the very initial section of the console message after I click "Run as Server" on Wildfly. It seems that it shows "Found bbword.war in deployment directory." Before I run it, I delete all in standalone/deployments/*. It start with an empty directory. It seems the "bbword.war" is copied to this directory whenever I run the server. I can't figure out. I use "find / -name bbword.war" on my computer but can't find this file. Really puzzled.

Update on this:

Eventually found out the problem: under the project 'bword', there is a ".setting" directory, which contains this file:
bword/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component

And there is a line in it: , where "bbword" was the previous deploy name I used. Remove this directory and in Maven, run "update" seems fixing this problem. In particular, I need to do both, first delete this dirctory, .setting, then update maven.

Several days wasted on this, but it's good to know about this.

Comment: do you have further Maven War Plugin configuration in your pom?

Comment: Please see the edit, which doesn't seem causing the problem.

Comment: Maybe it is related to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-3522

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and fixed it by having corrected those 2 files :

.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
=>deploy-name, etc

.project
=>name

Answer (score 1):

First, try deploying the maven-built artifact (bword.war) on your server(Do not forget to completely clean-up any Eclipse deployed artifacts first).
You can do this by simply moving the `bword.war` from your `/target` folder to your `path_to_wildfly/standalone/deployments` folder.
Check the server log file for message: `Registered web context: <web_context_name>` that should appear once your war is deployed.
If it says */bbword* - which is not what you expect, check whether you have a `jboss-web.xml` file in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` that specifies this as a `web-context` value.

If the maven artifact results in correct webcontext - */bword*, then it must be an Eclipse configuration issue. Have you tried updating the Eclipse project from Maven? :

1. right click on your project
2. select *Maven*
3. select *Update Project*
4. remove your project from Wildfly server, and add it again. If that does not help, try adding a new server runtime and add your project there. Last resort would be to create a new Eclipse workspace.

Good luck.

Comment: Tried all possibilities, and no success yet. The trouble is this message: "DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found bbword.war in deployment directory...", which appears in the the third line of the console output when the Wildfly server is run in Eclipse.

Comment: My another computer doesn't get this problem yet, with the same project.

Answer (score 0):

The listed solutions didnt work for me.
I had to create a completely new project in eclipse:

File->New->Project

named it correctly, and then copy-pasted the necessary code from the old project.
Now the server name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you'e running from intellij idea config then checkout artifact name in project structure. I had to rename it manually after fixing finalname tag in pom.xml. Better avoid any timestamp in artifact name.